# Waiting for async func to load value before setting rootVC(Coordinator pattern)

Tags: swift, firebase, uikit

Im having problem with setting `window.rootViewController` based on value downloaded from Firebase.

This is my `SceneDelegate:`

```
 var rootVC = MainCoordinator().start()
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
           window?.windowScene = windowScene
    window?.rootViewController = rootVC
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

My Coordinator protocol has start method that must return UIViewController so MainCoordinator start method is returnig showTabVC()

```
func showTabVC() -> UIViewController {

   guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {fatalError()}
  dataManager = DataManager(currentUserUid: user.uid)
  dataManager?.fetchCurrentUser(user:user.uid) //<- Should fetch user

  tabCoordinator = TabCoordinator(tabBarController: rootViewController as! UITabBarController, dataManager: dataManager!)
  let tabVC = tabCoordinator.start()

    return tabVC
}
```

As Im not very familiar with Combine this is how Im fetching user

```
 func fetchCurrentUser(user uid: String) -> AnyPublisher <UserInfo, Never> {

        return Future<UserInfo, Never> {promise in
            self.fetchUser(uid: uid) { result, _ in
                promise(.success(result))
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { [weak self] value in
            self?.currentUser = value
        }).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}


func fetchUser(uid: String,completition: @escaping (UserInfo,Error?)-> Void) {

        DataManager.userInfoRef.child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot, _ in

            let user = UserInfo(snapshot: snapshot as DataSnapshot)
            self.currentUser = user!
            completition(user!,nil)
        }

}
```

Depending on user info `tabCoordinator.start` should return admin or user flow but as my user does not load at the time I always face fatalError:

```
func start() -> UIViewController {

    if dataManager.currentUser?.admin == true {

        return adminFlow()
    } else if dataManager.currentUser?.admin == false {
      
        return userFlow()
    } else {
        fatalError("NoUserInfo")
    }
```

If I place for example userFlow() inside else instead of fatalError it would load and then completition handler from fetchUser would be trigered. How would I manage to wait for user info and then set rootVC?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the coordinator pattern here too. Don't jump straight to the coordinator if you are not warm with Swift and navigation. Like the SceneDelegate and this line:

```
 var rootVC = MainCoordinator().start()
```

Usually start would be the setup for the rootVC not an instance of it. Here is how I usually set up my MainCoordinator in the SceneDelegate (from: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/71/how-to-use-the-coordinator-pattern-in-ios-apps):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // create the main navigation controller to be used for our app
    let navController = UINavigationController()

    // send that into our coordinator so that it can display view controllers
    coordinator = MainCoordinator(navigationController: navController)

    // tell the coordinator to take over control
    coordinator?.start()

    // create a basic UIWindow and activate it
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = navController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

I guess that the reason why fetchCurrentUser isn't returning anything is because a publisher needs a subscription to deliver events and you aren't subscribing to the events that the fetchCurrentUser is delivering.

You can also remove handleEvents and use the returned result from the stream when you are subscribing to it.